# help with .net web code sharing design

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, integration

We have a number of interrelated systems that share a common service layer.  In addition, they are a number of common UI components.  To reduce cut and paste, we'd like to package up the code for use in all current and future projects.  Currently, the projects that we'll need to integrate with are ASP.net webforms and MVC 3 solutions.   I'd like folks input on the "best" way to proceed.

One implementation would be to create a separate web project (mvc) and have it share a common session with the other applications.  The benefit to this model would be that upgrades to the common component would not require all the applications call the common elements to be re-installed.  Unluckily, code separation for the common components (user and org management) isn't so simple.

Another method would be to wrap the code in a nuget package.  For the WebForms projects, I could be wrapped with the AddMvc3ToWebForms.  For the straight MVC projects it could just be installed as a folder.

any other alternatives?  I'd love to get a more plugable solution (e.g., MEFContrib) but I'm not familar enough with MVC to determine how to do it.

Any ideas would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "web service" or "wcf". It's very easy to create a web service to associate with other applications via (or even without) a user name and password authentication. Take a look on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/aspwebsvr.aspx)